# How do I count values in a column and match them with a specific row?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, case-when, grepl

I have the dataset that looks like this, where ID and emails correspond to a unique person. The remaining columns represent people named by that person/row. For example, a person with ID 1 and email address alex@gmail.com named Pete, Jane, and Tim when asked a question.

```
id email          john_b alex_a pete jane tim
1  alex@gmail.com NA     NA     1    1    1
2  pete@yahoo.com NA     1      1    NA   NA
3  jane@q.com     NA     NA     1    NA   1
4  bea@mail.co    NA     1      1    NA   NA
5  tim@q.com      NA     NA     1    NA   1
```

I need the new dataset to look like this, where a new column nomination represents the number of times that person/row was named in the rest of the dataset. For example, Pete was named by 5 people and gets 5 in the nomination column, on the row with the relevant email address. Jane was named once (by alex@gmail.com) and gets 1 in the nomination column, on the row with Jane's email address.

```
id email          john_b alex_a pete jane tim nomination
1  alex@gmail.com NA     NA     1    1    1   0 
2  pete@yahoo.com NA     1      1    NA   NA  5
3  jane@q.com     NA     NA     1    NA   1   1
4  bea@mail.co    NA     1      1    NA   NA  0
5  tim@q.com      NA     NA     1    NA   1   3
```

I have a sense that I need a combination of case-when and grepl here, but can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please include your data as an object pasted into the question with `dput(your_data)`; what code have you tried? This will make life easier for those who may want to help test and verify solutions.

Comment: I have posted an answer for your problem, I would be glad if you could check it.

Comment: Dear Rakhim, have you tried the code suggested by my friend akrun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I finally came up with a code that I hope to get you to what you expect. However, I could not think of any way to match `bea@mail.co` to `john_b`. It takes a mind far more brighter than mine for sure but if I could think of anything, I would update my codes here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tribble(
 ~email,          ~john_b, ~alex_a, ~pete, ~jane, ~tim,
  "alex@gmail.com", NA,     NA,     1,    1,    1,
  "pete@yahoo.com", NA ,    1,      1,    NA,   NA,
  "jane@q.com",     NA  ,   NA,     1,    NA,   1,
  "bea@mail.co",    NA,     1,      1,    NA,   NA,
  "tim@q.com",      NA ,    NA,     1,    NA,   1
)

# First we count the number of times each person is named
nm <- df %>%
  summarise(across(john_b:tim, ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "names", values_to = "nominations")
nm

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  names  nominations
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 john_b           0
2 alex_a           2
3 pete             5
4 jane             1
5 tim              3
```

Then we try to partially match every names with their corresponding emails. Here the only problem is `john_b` as I mentioned before.

```
nm2 <- nm %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(emails = map(names, ~ df$email[str_detect(df$email, str_sub(.x, 1L, 4L))])) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(emails))

nm2

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  names  nominations emails        
  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>         
1 alex_a           2 alex@gmail.com
2 pete             5 pete@yahoo.com
3 jane             1 jane@q.com    
4 tim              3 tim@q.com
```

And in the end we join these two data frames by `emails`:

```
df %>%
  full_join(nm2, by = c("email" = "emails"))

# A tibble: 5 x 8
  email          john_b alex_a  pete  jane   tim names  nominations
  <chr>          <lgl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1 alex@gmail.com NA         NA     1     1     1 alex_a           2
2 pete@yahoo.com NA          1     1    NA    NA pete             5
3 jane@q.com     NA         NA     1    NA     1 jane             1
4 bea@mail.co    NA          1     1    NA    NA NA              NA
5 tim@q.com      NA         NA     1    NA     1 tim              3
```

You can also omit the column `names` if you like. I just leave it their so that you can compare them together. If you could make some modification on john's email they would have perfectly matched.

Comment: Hey Anoushiravan R, thanks for this! It works, but doesn't match some of the names exactly. For example, name hollyg (and nomination number = 6) gets matched to two emails that contain "holl", holldan@gmail.com and hollyg@q.com. I need the function to mach to just one email, the latter. I am guessing str_detec is matching partial strings and not complete strings. Do you know if it's something that can be fixed?

Comment: Also, is there a way to match only to the names, and not the entire email address? I.e. I don't want the function to consider anything that follows @. For example, when I have a name Don and an email address tim@don.com, the sring matches to don.

Comment: The problem is there is no way to match certain names to emails. As shown in your desired output there needs to be a link between names and emails so I can put every corresponding counts in the row of their matching email.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Perhaps `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -email) %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(nominations = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), email = email[str_which(email, str_remove(first(name), "_\\w+$"))], .groups = 'drop') %>% complete(email = unique(df$email)) %>% left_join(df, .)`

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. The output is the same as mine, however, your code is far more concise and exquisite. Thank you. Do you know of any suitable resources for learning `regex` and string matching in particular string matching as my ability in that field leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @akrun By the way the problem is not with the codes I guess, there are certain emails that cannot be matched to any names as they share absolutely nothing in common.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR You could check some online tutorials like [this](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285).  But in the end, it is just your practice, trial and error etcc. comes handy in addition to understanding some of the syntax notations and its use.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR so for that, what is the desired output

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. Just for my last question, I've been learning R for less than a year and I really enjoyed it. Do you think hanging around in stackoverflow like answering some questions would be a good idea in someone's development as an R user and programmer? So far it has been so productive and little by little I am gaining confidence to answer even more questions.

Comment: @akrun for example `john_b` count is `0` but there is no way to match it to it's email which is `bea@mail.co` as mentioned in the desired output above in the question. The only difference with our outputs is that `NA` value in front of this email that should be `0`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Yes, that really helps in development of skills.   But, any method have its own pros and cons.  The cons in SO would be sometimes very aggressive behavior by somebody, or downvoting etc.  If you don't care that much about those, it would be a great platform because you get instantaneious response, increases the speed naturally, you may start thinking fast because a fraction of second counts.  Other options include the usual learning by taking a course or start a project.  Each have its own pros and cons

Comment: @AnoushiravanR that is very easy to replace i.t you can use `%>% mutate(nominations = replace_na(nominations, 0))`

Comment: @akrun you are absolutely right. Since the moment I started visiting here my learning rate has exponentially grown and as you mentioned correctly the speed factor makes you try to think faster to come up with a solution. Thank you very much for your time, it was great talking to you and you are one of my greatest inspirations here.

Comment: @akrun I understand, but for example when you counted the numbers and would like to match that name to email there is not way. Of course it is possible to replace every NA in this way. But there problem is not all `NA`s are zero they are the result of mismatched or unmatched names and emails.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR if there are not direct matches, then fuzzyjoin or stringdist join may be more useful

Answer (score 1):

If you organize your name columns in the same order as your email column then you could simply:

```
nomination <- colSums(df[, -(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)
names(nomination) <- NULL
df <- cbind(df, nomination)
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve. As you can imagine, organizing columns and rows in the right order can easily get out of hand with large datasets. Do you see another way of going about this?