# Filtering columns of a data frame according to another column

Tags: r, subset

I need to filter the data frame below according to the number of samples each `otu` occurs in.

```
   samples otu1 otu2 otu3 otu4 otu5
1        a    2    1    0    0    3
2        b    2    4    1    4    3
3        c    0    0    0    1    0
4        d    0    0    1    4    4
5        e    1    2    0    2    3
6        f    1    1    2    4    2
7        g    1    0    0    4    3
8        h    0    0    2    0    4
9        i    1    2    2    1    6
10       j    0    0    2    3    4
```

For example, to keep only the `otu`s that occur in >=80% of the samples, the output would be like:

```
   samples otu4 otu5
1        a    0    3
2        b    4    3
3        c    1    0
4        d    4    4
5        e    2    3
6        f    4    2
7        g    4    3
8        h    0    4
9        i    1    6
10       j    3    4
```

Comment: The wording of the question is fine, but the data must be reproducible. Try using the `dput` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    select(samples, where(~ is.numeric(.) && mean(. != 0) >= 0.8))
```

-output

```
#     samples otu4 otu5
#1        a    0    3
#2        b    4    3
#3        c    1    0
#4        d    4    4
#5        e    2    3
#6        f    4    2
#7        g    4    3
#8        h    0    4
#9        i    1    6
#10       j    3    4
```

---

Or if we are using an older `dplyr` version, use `select_if`

```
df1 %>%
   select_if(~ is.character(.)|is.numeric(.) && mean(. != 0) >= 0.8)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(samples = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j"), otu1 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), otu2 = c(1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), otu3 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L), otu4 = c(0L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L), otu5 = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help. Unfortunately, I got the following error: Error: could not find function "where"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @Gustavo can you check your `packageVersion('dplyr')` I used `1.0.4`

Comment: My version is 0.8.5. That's the version available in the update list.

Comment: @Gustavo what is your R version ?  I used R 4.0.4

Comment: @Gustavo try with the `select_if` updated code

Comment: Dear @akrun I was wondering if I could ask for your opinion on a very interesting problem.

Comment: My R version is 3.6.3. I'll update R and try to update dplyr. Using select_if, I got the same error. Thank you again for you help!

Comment: @Gustavo it is working fine for me though.  May be it is again the version problem

Comment: @AnoushiravanR can you tell me your problem

Comment: @akrun It is not my question and I left an answer to it. However, for some minor cases my codes cannot be useful. I was wondering if you could take a look at the problem and I would be very grateful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891164/how-do-i-count-values-in-a-column-and-match-them-with-a-specific-row/66895206?noredirect=1#comment118275423_66895206

Comment: @akrun I just solved the problem and successfully updated dplyr. Now the code is working fine! Thanks.

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. I owe you so much for all the things I've learned from you.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR i posted a code below your post.  I haven't checked all the cases, but it seems to be working with the pattern showed in column names